# Error 404: Not Found error showing Jeresy restful service

Tags: java, rest, jersey, websphere, javax

I created web dynamic project and context name is "restJeresy". and using websphere liberty server in my local.

When I hit url
http://localhost:9080/restJeresy/TestRestService/callService Below error showing

```
Error 404: Not Found
```

Can anyone please help me What I am missing?

Here is my code,

```
package com.demo;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;

@Path("/TestRestService")
public class HelloWorldService {

     @Path("/callService")
     @GET
    public String getMsg() {
        return "Hello World !! - Jersey 2";
    }
}
```

Web.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>restJeresy</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
      <servlet-name>Jersey RESTful Application</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
         <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.demo</param-value>
         </init-param>
         <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
      </servlet>
   <servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>Jersey RESTful Application</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>  
</web-app>
```

Comment: have you added created a `jvax.ws.rs.core.Application` extension which adds `HelloWorldService` to the application?  Does it work using Liberty's default jaxrs implementation (apache cxf) instead of jersey? To test that just get rid of the web.xml and add the jaxrs-2.0 feature in server.xml.

Answer (score 0):

The issue at servlet mapping in web.xml.Please check it

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0"> <display-name>restJeresy</display-name>

      <servlet>
          <servlet-name>Jersey RESTful Application</servlet-name>
          <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
               <init-param>
                <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
                <param-value>com.demo</param-value>
            </init-param>
             <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
          </servlet>    
<servlet-mapping>    
<servlet-name>Jersey RESTful Application</servlet-name>
          <url-pattern>/restf/*</url-pattern>    
</servlet-mapping>   
</web-app>
```

then try access http://localhost:9080/restJersey/restf/TestRestService/callService